# Standardized beta weights for a multilevel regression

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme, regression-coefficients, standardization

How can one obtain standardized (fixed effect) regression weights from a multilevel regression?

And, as an "add-on": What is the easiest way to obtain these standardized weights from a `mer`-object (from the `lmer` function of the `lme4`package in `R`)?

Comment: Specifically mer or you are asking for any linear model coefficients?

Comment: Actually I'm more interested on how to do it generally (I would standardize all variables beforehand, as in regular linear models, but I'm not sure if that approach is valid in MLMs). Above, I would like to see how it is done with lme4 objects. I rephrased the question accordingly!

Comment: You may be interested in this paper by Andrew Gelman and Iain Pardoe (2007) [Average Predictive Comparisons for Models with Nonlinearity, Interactions, and Variance Components](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9531.2007.00181.x).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply scale your explanatory variables to having mean of zero and variance of one before you put them in the model.  Then the coefficients will all be comparable.  The mixed effects nature of the model doesn't impact on this issue.

The best way to do it, and least likely to go wrong, is to use scale() before you fit the model.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know: rescaling to the grand mean (ignoring the group structure ...).

Answer (score 3):

For standard linear models regressed with lm() you can either scale() your predictors data or just use this simple formula:

```
lm.results = lm(mydata$Y ~ mydata$x1)

sd.y = sd(mydata$Y)
sd.x1 = sd(mydata$x1)
x1.Beta = coef(lm.results)["mydata$x1"] * (sd.x1 / sd.y)
```

Answer (score 3):

For a quick way to get at the standardized beta coefficients directly from any lm (or glm) model in R, try using `lm.beta(model)` from the QuantPsyc package. For example:

```
library("MASS")
glmModel = glm(dependentResponseVar ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data=myData)
summary(glmModel)

library(QuantPsyc)
lm.beta(glmModel)
```

Comment: In [this e-mail](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q4/004969.html) Ben Bolker translated this function to "lmer-land".

Comment: But the linked code that Ben provides isn't actually functional as written in that email, it doesn't look like. It includes words/pseudocode....

Edit: The answer to this question will provide the working code: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123366/lmer-standardized-regression-coefficients

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the output of your `lmer` model to `lmer.results`, `fixef(lmer.results)` will return the overall fixed effects coefficients.

Comment: They won't be "standardized" though, will they?  I read the question as wanting to know the size of fixed effects if the explanatory variables were all on the same scale.

Comment: I don't know that it is possible to get the standardised coefficients from a `mer` object - they don't appear in the summary, so I assume the `lme4` methods don't create them. `fixef()` will return all fixed effect information available from a `mer` object.

Comment: As Peter already commented: the focus of the question was about the 'standardized' coefficients ...