# lmer: standardized regression coefficients

Tags: lme4-nlme, regression-coefficients, standardization

I  have analyzed some data (the exact nature of which, I assume, is irrelevant for this question) using linear mixed effects models with the lmer() function from lme4.

There has been at least one question about standardized regression coefficients [previously](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22346/standardized-beta-weights-for-a-multilevel-regression/46317#46317), in which, obviously, there has been the recommendation to use the scale() function in order to obtain standardized predictors and outcome variables before entering these into a model.

Furthermore, in a comment on an answer, [@crash](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/14646/crash) posted a link to an [email](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q4/004969.html) by Ben Bolker, in which the latter provided a function, applying lm.beta() to "lmer-land".

The function, as provided there, looks like this:

```
lm.beta.lmer <- function(mod) {
   b <- fixef(mod)[-1]            
   sd.x <- apply(mod at X[,-1],2,sd)                                 
   sd.y <- sd(mod at y)
   b*sd.x/sd.y
}
```

Yet, the "mod at X" and "mod at y" parts are hyperlinked and appear not to resemble executable R code. Specifically, when trying to define this function, R outputs

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"b <- fixef(mod)[-1]
sd.x <- apply(mod at"
```

so apparently R does not like the spaces.

I am interested in how I would need to change the code of lm.beta.lmer() in order to successfully apply this to my lmer models, but my nooby R skills forbid me to do so.

If anyone provided a useful answer to this, I would deeply appreciate this.

Cheers, bunsen

**EDIT**
Thanks @Wolfgang, I was not aware of this. However, having changed the abovementioned code accordingly, i.e. writing mod@X and mod@y, I get the following output when applying the function to a model:

```
>lm.beta.lmer(mod)
Error in apply(mod@X[, -1], 2, sd) : 
no slot of name "X" for this object of class "lmerMod"
```

Apparently, the code fails to access the Field X in slot pp of the lmerMod object (of which the first column is labelled "(Intercept)", so I assume it is the one that should be deleted). Since I get this error, I do not know, whether the Field y of slot resp of this object will be accessed, but I guess not.

I have attempted various ways of changing the code in order to make it access the X and y fields of the respective slots, but failed. Which part am I doing incorrectly, or rather (since I do not tell the ways I've tried): which is a possible way to access these fields?

I have noticed, that most likely I will be faster using the scale() function, but I am eager to learn a solution to my question.

Thanks again!

Comment: The `mod at X` parts are supposed to be `mod@X`. Mailing lists often replace "@" with " at " to make it more difficult for spammers to farm e-mail addresses.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang. However, there are problems that follow and I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get at `X` and `y` using the `getME()` function. So, this should work:

```
lm.beta.lmer <- function(mod) {
   b <- fixef(mod)[-1]
   sd.x <- apply(getME(mod,"X")[,-1],2,sd)
   sd.y <- sd(getME(mod,"y"))
   b*sd.x/sd.y
}
```

Comment: Minor fix for cases when there there's only a single predictor (in which case this throws an error as the dim of getME(mod,"X")[,-1] = NULL) would be to coerce getME(mod,"X")[,-1] into something with dimensions ~ e.g., (although I'm sure there's a more efficient version and this may cause later problems!):

lm.beta.lmer <- function(mod) {
   b <- fixef(mod)[-1];
   sd.x <- apply(matrix(getME(mod,"X")[,-1]),2,sd);
   sd.y <- sd(getME(mod,"y"));
   b*sd.x/sd.y;
}